# How to get full url of the current page in bigcommerce stencil code?

Tags: bigcommerce, bigcommerce-stencil-cli

I'm trying to access either below:
https://testing.com/cat/?page=5
or
/cat/?page=5

via the bigcommerce object. However, after research I only found the below code:

```
{{ settings.request.absolute_path }}
```

This will only return me /cat/

but I'm missing of /cat/?page=5

So can anyone help me to how to achieve the above? any way I can access this?

I've below code written: (of course below wont work with absolute path)

```
{{#if settings.request.absolute_path '===' 'https://testing.com/cat/?page=5' }}
    <meta name="description" content="The fifth page of cat products available." >
{{/if}}
```

[bigcommerce object](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects/schemas#settings)

Answer (score 0):

pagination.category.current should work for you on category pages. It may be different on Brand pages.

I like the idea.

Comment: Hi this code only returns page number. So output only 5. What I want is the url like /cat/?page=5. With this code my if condition never works

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the most efficient solution, but you could try something like:

```
{{#if settings.request.absolute_path '===' '/cat/'}}
  {{#if pagination.category.current '===' 5}}
    <meta name="description" content="The fifth page of cat products available." >
  {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Or you could try incorporating the {{concat}} helper with something like:

```
{{#if (concat settings.request.absolute_path '?page=5') '===' 'https://testing.com/cat/?page=5' }}
  <meta name="description" content="The fifth page of cat products available." >
{{/if}}
```

Both will get the job done, but the second one might be closer to the answer you are looking for.

Comment: first solution didn't work somehow as its through the server error so not sure what's wrong thr. However, the concat solution is good but we need to concat three values first is the category: /cat/ (settings.request.absolute_path) then "?page=" and lastly pagination.category.current (5).
The problem here is I can't concat 3 values together as only allows two. So do you know how I can assign this to variable and then concat variable and and pagination.category.current.  
Please let me know if you've any idea around variables.

Comment: Have you tried running {{concat}} twice within the {{if}} statement?

{{#if (concat settings.request.absolute_path (concat '?page=' pagination.category.current)) '===' '/cat/?page=5' }}
  <meta name="description" content="The fifth page of cat products available." >
{{/if}}